# Angular - two (or more) services dependent on each other

Tags: angularjs, factory, angularjs-factory

I have little problem/question with learning Angular.

Let's say I have 2 factories:

**UserFactory**

```
module.factory('User', ['$http', '$injector', 'Post', function($http, $injector, Post){
    User.prototype = {
        getPosts: function(){
             **code**
             ** Some Post factory operations (Post.getPostsByUserId(data.id) or something like that)**
        }
    }
}
```

**PostFactory**

```
module.factory('Post', ['$http', '$injector', 'User', function($http, $injector, Post){
    Post.prototype = {
        getUser: function(){
             **code**
             ** Some User factory operations (User.getUserById(data.id) or something like that)**
        }
    }

}
```

I think I don't have to say that I get circular dependency error, but how to deal with this problem?
I wanted to do something like this in view.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{ user.name }}<br />
    <div ng-repeat="post in user.getPosts()">
        {{post.title}}
    </div>
</li>
```

Or in second way:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    {{ post.title }}<br />
    {{ post.getUser().name }}
</li>
```

I also want to have caching in my models so I don't have to re-download data  from server if it was used before.
Any ideas? Or have I to use in every controller two factories.
First get user and that do foreach on `user.posts` (user.posts is an array of posts id) and use `Post.getPostById(id)`

I have thought also about functions in `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.getUserById();
$rootScope.getPostById();
```

I would use in these functions my factories and then in view:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{ user.name }}<br />
    <div ng-repeat="post in user.posts">
        {{ getPostById(post).title }}
    </div>
</li>

<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    {{ post.title }}<br />
    {{ getUserById(post.user_id).name }}
</li>
```

What's the proper way to do that?
Or maybe should I extend baseController? (I don't know how to extend objects/prototypes in angular and JS)

**EDIT: Fiddle with interpolate error and circular dependency:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/Hooyek/gxjuoted/

**EDIT2: Fiddle with $rootScope working:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hooyek/gxjuoted/4/

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Angular is pretty loose with Dependency Injection, and just because services reference each other doesn't mean they are circular.  In fact, from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), Angular uses [Constructor Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/), which enforces order of initialization to prevent circular dependencies.

Comment: @Claies As i wrote I have tried only one way. I am wondering how to deal with that in a "proper" way because I am on the begining of my adventure with Angular.

Comment: the pseudocode you provided here doesn't illustrate any flaws which would generate any errors for angular;  if you tried it and got an error, presenting the real code and the error will help us sort out your error.  If, instead, this is an attempt to ask opinions of different coding styles related to the problem, that isn't appropriate for this format.  This site works in tangible problems and solutions, not speculative theory.

Comment: @Claies And here is the fiddle with `$rootScope`: http://jsfiddle.net/Hooyek/gxjuoted/4/ it works, but is it "proper way"? Won't this complicate my code later?

Comment: @Claies Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hooyek/gxjuoted  with interpolate and circural dependency errors, I have tried to do it with managers like I wrote at the begining.